# A JNI error met in quick-cocos

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I coded an app with quick-cocos2d-x.
The app works well in the last 18 months.
But today, an unknown error shows out and it always crush when finish payment on Google.

I located the position where the crush happens.

xxx.java

```
myApp.this.runOnGLThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        Log.d(TAG, obj.toString());
        C.androidPaymentFinished(obj.toString());
    }
});
```

The function is a native static function to call the CPP part.

C.java

```
class C{
    public static String void androidPaymentFinished(String data);
    // other functions
}
```

main.cpp

```
void Java_com_company_util_C_androidPaymentFinished(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring data) {
    const char* str1 = jstringTostring2(data);
    PlatformAPI::googlePayFinish(str1);
}
```

During using JNI to link CPP part.

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x9bbbfe80
```

The error log above shows out and the program crushed.

But it is strange that the app never crush before and the code NEVER changed. And when the crush happened, other APP with the same code have not crushed for even one time.

Did anybody meet this situation before?

Additional

I think the error occurs at the time when the java code try to call the native function. And no matter what the CPP part do, the program always crush after a few seconds. I annotated the cpp code and made it a blank function, but the program still crushed.

And I'm sure the input is valid. I output a log before C.androidPaymentFinished(data) is called, and data is a valid JSON style String.

```
{"status":"ok","newCredits":222839450,"newGems":10,"newTickets":600,"stopIndex":5,"reward":100000,"sku":"com.company.app.item.000001"}
```

Comment: We need to know more precisely where the JNI error occurs. Also, what do the implementations of `jstringToString` and `googlePayFinish` look like? From what you've shown us so far you seem to assume that all input parameters always are valid, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that androidPaymentFinished() in C.java actually does not return void but a String(My apology for posting a wrong description before). So the return in CPP part is different from the return in Java part. That causes memory leak and results in crush.